# VARCHAR, InnoDB MySQL, is inline allocated space variable or fixed?

Tags: mysql, innodb, varchar

For a log table, I have a custom message column.

- It will never be updated.
- It will be searched with LIKE conditions.
- It will be capped at 1KB.

TEXT fields are slower than VARCHAR fields for lookups because they stored separately, while VARCHAR fields are stored inline.

What I don't know and couldn't find here on SO (there already are hundreds of VARCHAR vs TEXT questions) or on the MySQL docs: **when inlined, do VARCHAR fields take at least the number of bytes specified, or do they vary?.**

One of the goals is keeping the size on disk as small as possible. If VARCHAR does not vary, then TEXT has a significant advantage. Otherwise, VARCHAR will provide both lookup speed and small disk footprint.

EDIT: For clarification, if the field is created with ASCII collationwith and a size of 100, a string of length 10 will take 10 bytes or 100 bytes on disk (for inline VARCHAR)?

Comment: I don't think you can have maximum lookup speed and minimum storage size at the same time. You'll probably have to choose.

Comment: Yeah, but since there are multiple data types, there are multiple choices. I'm trying to make the best choice :).

Comment: Before voting to close, consider leaving a comment. All I see is a question which fits the FAQ.

Comment: Don't take it personally. Some regulars who haven't read the FAQ just don't like questions that do not feature source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) say the min size occupied by a varchar is 1B and the max is 256B (before 5.0.3) and 65,536B (after 5.0.3)

But when it comes to look-up performance always searching on a `char` will be faster then a `varchar` (it makes sense since you will have fixed size rows then the look-up process will be much faster because it can calculate exactly where in the data the desired value is )

**EDIT**

If you have `varchar(100)` and inserted a string of 10 chars then the space occupied is **11B** (varchar uses 1B to store the length of the string max. 255 for ver <= 5.0.3 and 2B for ver > 5.0.3 since max. 65,535).
If you have `char(100)` and inserted a string of 10 chars then the space occupied is **100B**.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined by the length of what you enter with a 1-2 byte prefix,

i.e

```
VARCHAR(4)  Storage Required
''          1 byte
'ab'        3 bytes
'abcd'      5 bytes
```